Blender adds all faces to Vertex Group when only extruded faces from cylinder are selected
To start have a cylinder with 256 sides, select all sides and checker deselect, then extrude along normals, that should get you here.

Next select all 5 faces of one of the extruded areas and select -> select similar -> Face Regions.
(this was the easiest way I've found to do this, though I am not sure if it is the most correct/efficient)

Here is where the weird behavior starts to happen.
I can only add the entire mesh to a vertex group
"+" -> assign -> deselct -> select
results in this group

Now what has me confused is if I invert the selection before creating a vertex group, it creates the inverse no problem.

I've noticed I can create a Face map of the region I want selected but I don't believe it is possible to create a displacement from a face map.
How can I create a vertex group that would fit my needs?
The reason I only want the extruded faces selected is because I am trying to add a displacement to the outside of the extruded faces similar to the creation you see here, I'd like to try making similar shapes and such.

If you think about it you're actually assigning every vertex of the object to the group because they are all selected even if the faces between the extruded sections aren't selected. Incidentally just using Ctrl-Numpad + after you did your initial extrusion will select all the required faces without having to select your 5 faces and use Select Similar....

It does not even have anything to do with Vertex Groups specifically. You get the same effect when you select faces in Edit Mode and then switch from Face Select to Vertex Select (or Edge Select).
If you select faces that are adjacent to an unselected face between them, this works because you are in Face Select mode and you decide which faces are selected and which are not.

However, the unselected face shares vertices with the surrounding selected faces. When you are now switching to Vertex Select, Blender selects all vertices which are part of the previous selected faces. But this vertex selection does not "know" or "care" about faces. The area between vertices will be shown as selected when all vertices building its bounding edges are selected.

And so if you would now switch back to Face Select mode, the previous state with the unselected face in the center cannot be restored. Because Blender only "knows" that all bounding vertices/edges of the face are selected, so the face itself will be selected too.
The other way round is, when you select a face, you cannot at the same time have one of its vertices unselected. Because by definition a face is built from edges, which are built from connections between vertices. If you see it as levels which are building up upon each other, you cannot select a higher level geometry like a face without selecting all of its components, like the edges on a lower level. And you cannot select an edge without selecting its start and end vertices.
The same thing happens with edges as well, not only faces as you can imagine: When there is an unselected edge between two selected edges, the vertices building the start and endpoint of the unselected edge are part of the selected edges, so they get selected if you switch from Edge Select to Vertex Select and now the previously unselected edge is selected as well, since both its vertices are selected.

Now the thing is, the name already says it all: those groups are Vertex Groups, you can store vertices in there and assign weights to them. They are not Face Groups.
One way to do store face information would be using material slots, since materials need surfaces to shade an object and are therefore not assigned to only vertices or edges, but faces. So selecting faces and assigning a material slot to them stores face selections in a way.
Another possibility would be to create a new UV map (you do not have to mess up the one you need for texturing if this applies to the object) and unwrap face selections step by step. With UV Sync Selection enabled in the UV Editor you can select UV faces to get the Edit Mode face selections from them.
Of course these workarounds are not as convenient as Vertex Groups and especially you cannot use them in modifiers where you often have the option to select a group which should be affected by the modifier.
